# What are the ports used for in a practical sense in the Interaction Net paradigm?

Tags: interaction-nets

I have briefly read through much of the [Interaction Combinators](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Interaction-Combinators-Lafont/6cfe09aa6e5da6ce98077b7a048cb1badd78cc76) paper, and am looking at [this blog post](https://zicklag.github.io/blog/interaction-nets-combinators-calculus/) for some help, but they both just say basically "each node in the graph must have one active port, and zero or more secondary ports", without explaining what ports are or what ports do, from a software and programming language standpoint.

[image]

I don't understand what this diagram means. I get the generic concept of "ports" as sort of input and output things (like data socket ports on the server), but I don't get how exactly they work in this interaction net context.

What are the active ports for, and what are the auxiliary ports for? If you were to think of this as a programming language or computation, what role do the ports play? I know there are some examples of "programming languages for interaction nets" like [inpla](https://github.com/inpla/inpla/blob/fd68179ca72de7fe5f2459e860cc4fe196c6d3c4/Gentle_introduction_Inpla.md), but there is no standard yet, so not looking for how to write interaction nets as code necessarily, but just to understand how the ports would work when code executes, at least at a high level. Something more for the lay programmer than a mathematician or computer scientist.

Answer (score 3):

The point of the principal ports is to indicate when a rewrite rule should be activated. In interaction nets, all rewrite rules start with two nodes with connected principal ports. If two ports are connected where one or both are auxiliary, then there will be no rewrite rules associated to that link. Why would we want this? First is to simplify graphical computation. In a more general graph rewrite setup, one would need to solve the subgraph isomorphism problem to see if a subgraph matches the input of the rewrite rule. This could be highly nontrivial. By contrast, checking that two connected ports are principal is rather trivial. Second is determinism. Two rewrite rules cannot overlap without being identical, removing ambiguity. Interaction nets satisfy a strong form of confluence called "strong confluence" which states that all evaluation paths ultimately perform, verbatim, the same collection of rewrites, just in different orders. This means we don't need to worry about evaluation order or synchronization, for example.

The role of ports is, I think, a bit clearer in the original presentation of interaction nets where each port was polarized as either being positive or negative. There, only positive ports could be connected to negative ports. Agents with positive principal ports can be seen as constructors which are waiting to be consumed while agents with negative principal ports can be seen as destructors waiting for something to consume. This idea would appear in your diagram where the arrows of nil and cons are positive while the arrow of append is negative. In such a set up, in order for a destructor to work on an expression, it must have a constructor on top; that is, it has to be in head-normal form. So we can see these ports as enforcing a paradigm where computation happens exactly and only on the heads of expressions. This gives interaction nets some of the same attributes as lazy evaluation without compromising on sharing.